# Dynamic import from node_modules in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to import a component from **node_modules** like this. But it not working.

( created project by create-react-app )

```
import React from 'react';
const a = '@sarin/coral-button';
import(a);
```

[This is an error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUUJI.png)

[This is an error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akhdo.png)

[This is an error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE3qJ.png)

and I have tried to config webpackAlias with **customize-cra** and **react-app-rewired** like this in

"config-overides.js" but i still got the same error as before.

```
module.exports = override( 
addWebpackAlias({
  ["@sarin/coral-button"]: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@sarin/coral-button"),
}),
```

but if i import **statically** it will working.

```
import React from 'react';
import('@sarin/coral-button');
```

Comment: At which line exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan at line 3

Comment: when you import **statically** do still get the same error?

Comment: No it worked if import statically.

Comment: Strange. You could checkout this link if you haven't 
https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import

Comment: Have you tried this `import * from a`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I got an invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack does not try to find the variables inside your javascript file. In your case, you have defined some variable a with the path. Then you are using dynamic import. While building, webpack will only perform static analyze. It will not try to find the variable a inside your javascript file. so the correct way is to specify your path directly inside your dynamic import statement.

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "user-defined" */'@sarin/coral-button');
```

Comment: Thank you.From your answer that mean there is no way to import node_modules by defined variable with the path isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. you cannot specify the whole path as dynamic inside import() statement

Answer (score 0):

From the document of dynamic import is explained

> Here specifier will be interpreted the same way as in an import declaration (i.e., the same strings will work in both places). However, while specifier is a string it is not necessarily a string literal; thus code like import(`./language-packs/${navigator.language}.js`) will work—something impossible to accomplish with the usual import declarations.

So, Let's change your code to use template string.

```
import React from 'react';
const a = '@sarin/coral-button';
import(`${a}`);
```

I have been tested from the latest create-react-app with below code and it work correctly

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const a = './hello'
import(`${a}`).then(hello => console.log('HELLO', hello.default))

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and change code style to use async/await it work correctly too.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

(async () => {
  const a = './hello';
  const b = await import(`${a}`);
  console.log(b.default)
})()


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```